# Configuring resilience4j to handle failures in circuit breaker

Tags: java, spring-boot, circuit-breaker, resilience4j

So I have this in the `application.yml`

```
  configs:
    default:
      registerHealthIndicator: true
      slidingWindowSize: 10
      minimumNumberOfCalls: 5
      permittedNumberOfCallsInHalfOpenState: 3
      automaticTransitionFromOpenToHalfOpenEnabled: true
      waitDurationInOpenState: 5s
      failureRateThreshold: 50
      eventConsumerBufferSize: 10
      recordExceptions:
        - org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException
      ignoreExceptions:
        - org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException
```

Config is like so:

```
    @Bean (name="defaultRestCall")
    public RestCall defaultRestCall(CircuitBreakerRegistry registry,
                                    RetryRegistry retryRegistry) {
        CircuitBreaker cb = registry.circuitBreaker(APP_NAME);
        Retry retry = retryRegistry.retry(APP_NAME);
        return new RestCall(APP_NAME, cb, retry);
    }
```

When I make the dependant service down this is the response I get

```
2021-09-29 16:15:15,417 INFO com.commons.rest.handler.AbstractRestResponseHandler [http-nio-9006-exec-5]: In handle(sample_service, io.github.resilience4j.circuitbreaker.CallNotPermittedException)
2021-09-29 16:15:15,420 INFO com.connector.ExternalServiceConnector [http-nio-9006-exec-5]: failure : true
2021-09-29 16:15:15,423 INFO com.connector.ExternalServiceConnector [http-nio-9006-exec-5]: CircuitBreaker 'sample_service' is OPEN and does not permit further calls
2021-09-29 16:15:15,425 DEBUG com.commons.web.support.GlobalExceptionHandler [http-nio-9006-exec-5]: [com.commons.exception.ResourceNotFoundException] with error Id, error code and message [{ "errors": [{ "errorCode": "NOT_FOUND", "message":"Unable to access data from Dependant Service"}], "errorId":"7685c6bd-0202-4c0b-b1d8-70f5b62c2ddf", "errorCount":1}]
2021-09-29 16:15:15,430 WARN org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver [http-nio-9006-exec-5]: Resolved [com.commons.exception.ResourceNotFoundException]
```

Is the logs conveying the correct exceptions? I can see the `open` circuit breaker state but wondering what follows looks correct.

Comment: from the docs: -> `failureRateThreshold : When the failure rate is equal or greater than the threshold the CircuitBreaker transitions to open and starts short-circuiting calls.` I suppose that your application reached this point.

Comment: Generally resilience4j when the circuit breaker is open throws CallNotPermittedException and you can catch the exception and handle it as you think best to have a nice fallback